# Why return Interfaces eg IEnumerable, IList - example of refactoring

Tags: c#

Question:  Have I got this example backwards?

Is the reason to return Interface so that:

Try1:

```
public class Thing
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }

    public IList<Thing> giveMeAllThings() 
    {
        IList<Thing> listOfThings = new List<Thing>();
        Thing thing1 = new Thing { name = "phone", age = 3 };
        Thing thing2 = new Thing { name = "waterbottle", age = 2 };
        Thing thing3 = new Thing { name = "pinecone", age = 17 };
        listOfThings.Add(thing1);
        listOfThings.Add(thing2);
        listOfThings.Add(thing3);

        return listOfThings;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void UnitTestThings()
    {
        Thing thing = new Thing();
        IEnumerable<Thing> listOfThings = thing.giveMeAllThings(); 

        Assert.AreEqual(3, listOfThings.Count()); // linq count
        Assert.IsTrue(listOfThings.Any(t => t.name == "phone" && t.age == 3));
        Assert.IsTrue(listOfThings.Any(t => t.name == "waterbottle" && t.age == 2));
        Assert.IsTrue(listOfThings.Any(t => t.name == "pinecone" && t.age == 17));
    }
}
```

try2.  I figure out that as I only need IEnumerable then I can just return that.

```
public IEnumerable<Thing> giveMeAllThings() 
    {
        IList<Thing> listOfThings = new List<Thing>();
        Thing thing1 = new Thing { name = "phone", age = 3 };
        Thing thing2 = new Thing { name = "waterbottle", age = 2 };
        Thing thing3 = new Thing { name = "pinecone", age = 17 };
        listOfThings.Add(thing1);
        listOfThings.Add(thing2);
        listOfThings.Add(thing3);

        foreach (Thing t in listOfThings)
            yield return t;
    }
```

**Edit:**
So if I need a List in one method but not another, then the most 'General' interface possible to return is an IList:

```
public IList<Thing> giveMeAllThings() 
    {
        IList<Thing> listOfThings = new List<Thing>();
        Thing thing1 = new Thing { name = "phone", age = 3 };
        Thing thing2 = new Thing { name = "waterbottle", age = 2 };
        Thing thing3 = new Thing { name = "pinecone", age = 17 };
        listOfThings.Add(thing1);
        listOfThings.Add(thing2);
        listOfThings.Add(thing3);

        return listOfThings;
    }

[TestMethod]
    public void UnitTestThings()
    {
        Thing thing = new Thing();
        IEnumerable<Thing> listOfThings = thing.giveMeAllThings(); 
        Assert.AreEqual(3, listOfThings.Count()); // linq count
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void UnitTestThingsWhereINeedAnActualList()
    {
        Thing thing = new Thing();
        IList<Thing> listOfThings = thing.giveMeAllThings();
        Assert.AreEqual(3, listOfThings.Count); // List count
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the reason to return Interface so that:

The main reason to do this is that, by returning the most "general" purpose interface possible, you have more flexibility in changing your internal implementation to something "better" (ie: more efficient, simpler code, whatever the criteria may be) later, without breaking your public API.

For example, if you switch from `IList<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`, you could switch your code around to use iterators (`yield return`) instead of a collection.  You may decide that a different collection (instead of `List<T>`) works better in your code, and switch to it.  If that second collection didn't implement `IList<T>`, it would require you to change your public API.

Comment: Hi Reed - many thanks.. I've edited the question so that my most general interface needed is an IList.  However if I wanted to use iterators, I guess that can't in this example.

Comment: @Dave: True - but by returning an `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>`, you've opened up the possibility of using (internally) a different class than list.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could return `ICollection<Thing>` which has `.Count`, `Thing[]` which has `.Length`, or `IEnumberable<Thing>` which has the linq extension method `.Count()` .  You don't necessarily need `IList<Thing>` if you just want the count of elements.

Using interfaces or basic return types also shows intent as to how the return type is intended to be used.

I tend to use `IEnumerable<T>` most of the time.

I consider using arrays (or `IList<T>`) when indexing is required.

Answer (score 0):

An IEnumerable is less specific than an IList. I try to return the least specific thing that will still work.

Supposing I were returning an IDictionary, there's the tempation to return:

```
IEnumerable<ICollection<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>>
```

But I think that doesn't accurately describe what is happening, even though it is less specific than:

```
IDictionary<Key, Value>
```